# Is it possible to use the cast API from a chome app? how to bypass the receiver selection popup?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, chromecast, google-cast

Does anyone know, is the cast API supported for use from a chrome app?  It initializes fine, says there are receivers available but I can't get a session - when I call requestSession nothing happens at all, neither success nor error callbacks are called, no window is displayed.

Maybe I'm approaching this all wrong...what I'm trying to do seems like it should be relatively straight-forward, but it really seems like google has deliberately prevented this.  All I'm trying to do is hook my IR remote up to my chromecast for media playback controls (play/pause/seek).  Even if the requestSession method worked, it really wouldn't give the user experience I want - it would still require the user to select the receiver from the popupmenu UI whenever they want to use their IR remote - far from friendly.  Instead I'd like to be able to pre-configure which chromecast the IR remote is bound to...and then it would always just connect to whatever app/session is currently running on that receiver to issue play/pause/seek commands.

I could implement this as a browser extension instead, and I'm sure I could get it functional that way...but that would be even less user-friendly (not to mention I'm already using some app-only APIs for the IR-receiving side of it which would have to be re-worked to other methods).

edit: Ok, after a bit more looking I've found this which I guess mostly answers my question https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=287254 ....but the question about the popup still stands...even if using an extension is there any way to bypass the reciever-selection popup that requires user interaction?

Comment: It looks like that crbug has a good discussion about the question about bypassing user action.